# Is Mesodae's Lantern effect recurring?

Tags: seasons

Mesodae's Lantern states

> Your energy reserve is decreased by 1. At the end of the round, receive 3 crystals.

My question is, do you receive 3 crystals one time immediately after playing it, or do you go 3 crystals at the end of each round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Régis Bonnessée, who is the designer of the game posted in this [boardgamegeek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/980916/question-about-mesodaes-lantern/page/2):

> The lantern give you 3 crystals each round.
>
> It's a permanent effect like Titus (see the symbol).

Answer (score 2):

You receive 3 crystals at the end of each round while it is in play. The symbol at the bottom left of the card indicates that the effect is continuous, as all end-of-round triggers (that I can remember) are.